# Function keys in Apple Keyboard doesn't work as expected in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am using apple keyboard. To get the default functionality of the function keys, I need to press fn+Function key. This is quite annoying since I frequently use the function keys for debugging. Is there any way I can get the default functionality out of the function keys. i.e Get the effect of pressed Fn key without having to actually press it.

Answer (score 1):

Then check on the [Mactel documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) for your model (each model seems to have slightly different). To find which model use the following command in the terminal

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
```

Documentation for the MacBookPro 5,5 13" MBP 2009 is as follows:

> To swap the fn key functionality (e.g. use fn+F1 to dim the LCD
>   etc..), edit /etc/pommed.conf and set the variable fnmode to 2
>
> gksudo gedit /etc/pommed.conf

while for that for the MacBookPro 11,1 13" MBP (late 2013) is:

> By default, the F keys serve their traditional function by pressing
>   the "fn" key. For example, by default the "F1" key lowers display
>   brightness and "fn+F1" is the traditional F1. I switched this behavior
>   on all the F keys by adding a command to /etc/rc.local
>
> sudo nano /etc/rc.local and add before "exit 0"
>
> echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode

Comment: `echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` worked for me on MacBookPro 11,1. Thanks!